# VB replace a character into a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to replace a character into a string
for example i have a string

> ABCD^>

and I want to change the ^ to

> {enter}

and > to

> {tab}

I recently have this code but I can not find a way out.

```
Dim temp As String
temp = TextBox1.Text
For Each chr As String In temp
If chr = "^" Then
chr = Replace(chr, "^", "{enter}")
End If
TextBox1.Text += chr
MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text)
Next
```

I also use this for keypress event in textbox but still doesn't work

```
texts = Replace(TextBox2.Text, "^", "{enter}")
texts = Replace(TextBox2.Text, ">", "{tab}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim temp as String = TextBox1.Text
temp = temp.Replace("^", "{enter}").Replace(">", "{tab}")
TextBox1.Text = temp
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that can be removed from your code, ***non necessary variables and your use of your loop***.

Here is what I would do...no need to loop.

```
MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.Text.Replace("^", "{enter}").Replace(">", "{tab}"))
```

> **I also use this for keypress event in textbox but still doesn't work**

According to your code, I don't see where you were doing this at in the keypress event. Anyway's you still can capture the key that was pressed and perform your logic as needed, but I do not see an attempt that you tried this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will work for you.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Const EnterTag As String = "{enter}"
    Const TabTag As String = "{tab}"

    If Me.TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("^") > -1 Then
        curLoc = Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart
        Me.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("^", EnterTag)
        Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = curLoc + EnterTag.Length
    End If

    If Me.TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">") > -1 Then
        curLoc = Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart
        Me.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(">", TabTag)
        Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = curLoc + TabTag.Length

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: sir am I right that the meaning of `Me.TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(">") > -1` is when I type in the textbox it automatically change to the `EnterTag` or `TabTag` because when I used `TextBox1.Text = replace(TextBox1, ">", {enter}")` the text will change after I type again.